# SQL query update column value twice in single query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a text column named `data` which has value in format

```
"`set1:val1,val2|set2:val3`"
```

so I have 2 sets field and n number of value fields in each set. I know this isn't normalized or proper approach to store data but it's a legacy project I can't change the schema now.

Now I need a single query given two values for each sets say `val4 and val5` I need my final data field to be

```
"`set1:val1,val2,val4|set2:val3,val5`"
```

I'm really not an expert in SQL query so need an update query for above. Note that I will always get only two values for each set and need to append in existing set values.

Comment: your question is not clear to me ... try add a proper data sample  .. and the expected  result   ( and use a proper formatiing for the data)

Comment: you can concat it

Answer (score 1):

This is an ugly solution to an ugly problem

```
UPDATE table
SET data = CONCAT(REPLACE(data,'|',',val4|'), ',val5')
WHERE data = '...'
```

The REPLACE operation changes `set1:val1,val2|set2:val3` to `set1:val1,val2,val4|set2:val3`, and then the CONACT operation changes that to `set1:val1,val2,val4|set2:val3,val5`